# Python: How to get a specific column value while looping through a row of data

Tags: python

I am trying to extract data from Quandl and I want to get the Date and 'Open' value (respectively) for each row. However, I am not sure what I should. Been trying different method that hasn't worked out. Below is an example:

```
data = quandl.get("EOD/PG", trim_start = "2011-12-12", trim_end =
"2011-12-30", authtoken=quandl.ApiConfig.api_key)

data = data.reset_index()
sta = data[['Date','Open']]

for row in sta:
     price = row.iloc[:,1]
     date = row.iloc[:, 0]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing with the code you have provided is iterating through the column names, i.e. you get `'Date'` on the first iteration, and `'Open'` on the next (and last).

To iterate through a dataframe by row, you can use any one the `.iterrows()`, `.iteritems()` or `.itertuples()` methods.

For example,

```
for row in data.itertuples():
    price = row.Open
    date = row.Date
```

Having said so, iterating through a pandas dataframe is really slow. Chances are, whatever you intend to do could be done faster by making use of pandas' vectorization, i.e. without a loop.

Comment: Thanks. I look at vectorization later. However, if I can ask one follow-up question: How do I (only) get the price value without the index number.